# Why converting int from SqlDataReader to long results in InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssis, ssis-2012

I get an Invalid Cast Exception on the following line:

```
DestMinSeq = (long)rdr["MinSeq"];
```

When I change the query to cast MinSeq to BIGINT instead of INT, it works.

Question: why should it be illegal to cast a short to a long?

Environment:

```
VS 2012 SSIS project script task. 
ADO.NET connection manager. 
SQL Server 2012.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question: why should it be illegal to cast a short to a long?

You're trying to cast a *boxed* short to a long. You can see this without a database:

```
int x = 10;
object o = x;
long y = (long) o; // Bang!
```

If you cast to the right type when unboxing, then cast to the type you really want, it's fine:

```
DestMinSeq = (long)(int)rdr["MinSeq]";
```

(I *suspect* you want `int` rather than `short`, but you'll have to check.)

Comment: I really need a long. The query results can come from 2 database versions where the column is INT in one and BIGINT in the other. To be safe, I do the CAST in the query, so it should always return a signed 64 bit value.

Comment: @Metaphor: Right, in that case you should indeed put the cast in the query. But hopefully this has explained why it wasn't working before.

Comment: So that's what it is. I get boxed scalars from the reader. I should have figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: That solution might actually be best.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `rdr["MinSeq"]` is of type `object` (actually a `int` boxed as an object). When you try to cast the `object` as a `long` it then gives you an invalid cast because the compiler cannot simply *cast* an object of type `object` to something other than the actual boxed type (in this case `int`).

You can try this instead,

```
 DestMinSeq = Convert.ToInt64(rdr["MinSeq"]);
```

Or what @Jon Skeet suggested, which actually looks fancier,

```
 DestMinSeq = (long)(int)rdr["MinSeq"];
```

Comment: The second version will fail when the query returns a bigint, which it does.

Comment: Of course, for the same reason it failed when the code returned an `INT`. The first solution should handle both cases and more, like when the scalar is a `string` (a string representing a number that is).